# Setting compatibility flags on executables residing on removable media from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry, compatibility

**Edit:** On further investigation it seems the SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxxx string changes based on the subfolder on the removable media, so it's not the removable media's device ID at all. I can't seem to find any real information about what it is or how it's calculated though. I'll leave the original question below, but I guess what I'm *really* trying to ask is this:

How do I set compatibility flags for executables in various folders on removable media from a batch file?

Failing that, how can I calculate the SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxx string for any given folder on removable media?

**Edit 2:** On yet further investigation it seems the SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxxx string changes every time the removable media is reinserted - even when the same drive letter is assigned. I'm guessing what I'm wanting to achieve either isn't possible or is going to require something more powerful than a batch file.

Does anyone know how the SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxxx string is calculated?

**Final edit:** Okay, I've officially given up. It seems Microsoft themselves don't even know (or won't say) how this is calculated. [See here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/10442e93-1ae6-4bb1-8693-d476916f5292/windows-compatibility-setting-for-removable-media-questions?forum=windowscompatibility)

After some more testing it appears that *sometimes* the SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxxx value changes for the same file in the same location on the same removable media after the media has been ejected and re-inserted, but *sometimes* it stays the same between sessions. There appears to be no consistency as far as I can ascertain. Also - at least based on a cursory experiment - it doesn't use a SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxxx value for a USB stick, but it does for an SD card and a DVD. So there doesn't even appear to be any consistency in how removable media is treated more generally. It's seriously infuriating - so much so that I'm actually thinking it's going to be easier to completely re-think this project entirely so I don't have to deal with Microsoft's piss-poor documentation and opaque implementations.

*Original question is below for reference...*

**Getting removable media device ID in a batch file**

I've searched far and wide to try to find an answer to this but I can't seem to find any relevant information.

I have a batch file that loops through a directory and sets compatibility flags for a load of executables. The batch file is located in the same directory as the executables.

I'm using the following syntax to set the registry values:

`reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%~dp0Example.exe" /d "WINXPSP3 RUNASADMIN"`

This works fine when run from any location on internal drives - for example it'll add a registry entry as follows:

`C:\Directory\SubDirectory\Example.exe REG_SZ WINXPSP3 RUNASADMIN`

When run from removable media (in this example an SD card) it does exactly the same thing (though obviously replacing C:\ with the actual drive letter of the removable media). However the problem is that the compatibility flag isn't actually set on the executable, despite it being there in the registry.

Upon further investiagtion, when adding the compat flag manually then querying the registry, a key in the following format is added:

`SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxxx \Directory\SubDirectory\Example.exe (where x... is a hexadecimal value)`

So the Drive letter in the path is being replaced by the device ID (I think?) of the removable media.

So my question is this: is there a way I can get the device ID (or whatever it is) from within the batch file?

Ideally I'd like a way to test if the batch file is on removable media or not first and then I can use a simple IF statement to build the correct path regardless, however if not I'll settle for a way to just get the device ID and then I can keep two separate batch files around.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is the following command:

```ps
wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID, Description
```

It will check all logical disks and show you the device id plus whether it is a local or removable drive.

And you can edit it to show you only removable disk's deviceID like this:

```ps
wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID, Description | find "Removable Disk"
```

Or you could simply use:

```ps
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid
```

Whatever works best for your script.

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately both of those just return the drive letter assigned to the removable media, at least on both my Windows 10 machines anyway. If possible I need the SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxxx string. I'm looking into a possible solution using AutoHotkey, which isn't ideal but will do in a pinch. I'll post an anser here if I manage to get it working.

Comment: i gave you the command, to use it in script and store it in a variable where u could use it later you have to use
      set ID = wmic logicaldisk get deviceid
and then when u wanna refer to it use %ID% 
of course you don't have to name it ID, name it whatever you want

Comment: Yes, I know I can use it with a variable, but the command returns the drive letter assigned to the device (for example D:). I need a way to get the SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxxx device ID instead.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's not the device ID I'm looking for it seems. See the edit I've made to my above question.